# Left-string, variable matching in a DOS command?

Tags: string, batch-file, pattern-matching, dos

Is it possible to do a string pattern match in DOS? For instance I want to do the following:

```
if "%USERNAME" == "abc*" (echo 1)
```

I know the asterisk doesn't work here and I can't find an alternative. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if "%USERNAME:~0,3%" == "abc" (echo 1)
```

This  will substring your `%USERNAME` for 3 characters from the beginning

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You could use this if the rest of the string doesn't matter:

```
set str=politic
echo.%str%
set str=%str:~0,4%
echo.%str%
```

Something like string left on both parts.